# Choosing a threshold based on the likelihood ratio test

Tags: machine-learning, log-likelihood

I am stuck with a task of ratio test. Please help me with some advice.
We are studying the Linear Discriminant Analysis.
After projecting all the points on to "best" line the entire 2D dataset becomes two univariate normal distributions:
$$
N(w^T\mu_1,w^TC_1w), N(w^T\mu_2,w^TC_2w)
$$
I am asked to find an optimal threshold value (aka intersection of two univariate normal curves) by using the likelihood ratio test. I understand that all the terms of both normal distributions are just scalars after projection.
The likelihood ratio test assumes that:
$$
\frac{N(w^T\mu_1,w^TC_1w)}{N(w^T\mu_2,w^TC_2w)} > 1
$$
I suppose that if these "dot(w,mu)" etc are just scalars, so I can rewrite that as:
$$
\frac{N(\mu_1,\sigma_1)}{N(\mu_2,\sigma_2)} > 1
$$
and expand as the regular Gaussian.
My last step was:
$$
ln(\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1})-\frac{1}{2}(\sum_0^{N-1}\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2}-\sum_0^{N-1}\frac{(x-\mu_2)}{\sigma_2^2}) > ln(\gamma)
$$
and it reduces to:
$$
\sum_i^{N-1}\sigma_2^2(x_i-\mu_1)^2-\sigma_1^2(x_i-\mu_2)^2 > ln(\gamma)-\frac{2\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2}{ln(\frac{\sigma_2}{\sigma_1})}
$$
Please explain me how it works. Is this right direction? How to proceed with my results?

Comment: What is your question exactly? When ask "explain how it works," what is "it"?

Comment: I am stuck with that. I am not sure if this is right at all and how to proceed with that.

Comment: "it" - likelihood ratio test in this case

Comment: Your work is fine as far as I can tell. You can use either the likelihood ratio or the difference of log likelihoods as your statistic. If the statistic is larger/smaller than some threshold, then you accept/reject (which is which will depend on which is your null hypothesis). The choice of threshold will give different tests; one usually chooses it to match the desired significance level.

Comment: Thank you for your advice